# simple pointers to pointers

Tags: c, pointers, double-pointer

I know why this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cool_number(int **number) {
  int value = 42;
  int *p = &value;
  *number = p;
}

int main () {
  int *number;
  cool_number(&number);
  printf("number is %d\n", *number);
  return 0;
}
```

What I don't understand is why this doesn't (in my machine it prints `3700` or something like that).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cool_number(int **number) {
  int value = 42;
  int *p = &value;
  int **x = &p;
  number = x;
}

int main () {
  int *number;
  cool_number(&number);
  printf("number is %d\n", *number);
  return 0;
}
```

Why aren't both equivalent?

Comment: Your first example doesn't "work". Returning the address of a local variable is undefined behavior. It's a bug and only [appears to work by accident](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/445976).

Comment: That's true, but it's also not at all relevant to the question being asked, which is "why do these two function implementations do different things".  Even if the OP fixes that issue, they would still find that the two functions behave differently, and the original question would still stand.

Comment: @aroth: I think trying to reason about code that has undefined behavior is a waste of time. Fix that first before asking about pass by value vs. by reference. Even if he corrects the parameter passing this question could still be "why do these two function implementations do different things".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume they're not equivalent because `number` is passed by value, on the stack, as is standard for function parameters.  Any changes that you make directly to `number` inside of `cool_number()` are modifying the local copy on the stack, and are not reflected in the value of `number` in `main()`.

You get around this in the first example by dereferencing `number`, which tells the computer to modify some specific location in memory that you also happen to have a pointer to back in `main()`.  You don't have this in the second example, so all that happens is that you make the local `number` pointer point to somewhere else, without actually updating any memory location being referred to back in `main()`.  Thus nothing you do shows up once you get back to `main()`.

And since `value` is local to the `cool_number()` function, setting a reference to it that will be accessed after `cool_number()` returns isn't guaranteed to work and certainly shouldn't be used in any code outside of a trivial/toy example.  But in this specific instance it's not really related to why you're seeing different results between the two pieces of code.

Answer (score 3):

both are evil as they capture the address of a stack variable.

Second one doesn't do what you expect because you are assigning directly to the parameter number, which is only temporary,  the first one changes something the parameter number pointers to,  which is the same thing as number in main points to.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, in both cases, your code is wrong.

1. In the first case, you are returning an address to a variable allocated on stack, which will be deallocated as soon as the function returns.
2. In the second case, the error of the first case exists, plus you are passing number by value, so an updation to number will not get reflected in the caller function.

In 'C', arguments are always passed by value. So, you cannot update the argument passed as it is. For Ex:

```
int func(int a)
{
  a = 5; // In this case the value 5 will not be reflected in the caller as what is updated is the local copy of a on the stack
}

int func(int *a)
{

  *a = 5; // This update will show in caller as you are directly updating the memory pointed to by a
   a = malloc(4); //This update will not show in caller as again you are updating the local copy of stack       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cool_number(int **number) {
  int value = 42; /* this "value" hold 42 value, 
                     and it lifetime is only in this function */
  int *p = &value; /* here we get the address of "value" in memory */
  *number = p;
}

int main () {
  int *number;
  cool_number(&number);  /* after this function the "value" in memory had been recyled
                            and may be used by other program */
  printf("number is %d\n", *number); /* so when we print value here it will be 
                                 a unpredictable value, somehow may be crash */
  return 0;
}
```

both the same principle